# double result after substracting

Tags: java

I have a project where I receive a cost of a product and the amount paid. I need to derive the smallest amount of coins that will make the change.
I use double variables for the price and the paid amount, as well as the change: double change = double paidAmount-double cost;
My problem is that for 1 - 0.66 I receive 0.33999998 instead of 0.34
What type of variables should I use to get exactly two digit after the floating point result?
Please not that I must not use BigNumber

Answer (score 0):

Please try  DecimalFormat  format double

```
double change  =  1 - 0.66;
double result = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("#.00").format(change));
System.out.println(result);
```

0.34

Comment: It would be better to just use `BigDecimal` everywhere, so that the value being represented is the *exact* value desired.

Comment: @Jekozo said : Please not that I must not use BigNumber

Comment: Technically `BigDecimal` doesn't use `BigNumber` since that isn't a class...